# Kendo UI: Not able to add footerTemplate to grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am trying to display the count of the field in the footerTemplate. 
Follow is the fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/ajoyug/8/edit

However, without the footerTemplate it works fine. But as soon as I add the footerTemplate, it stops working.

Inside the aggregateResult object I am getting the value of count. But then how shall I add it to the footerTemplate?

Kindly help me out.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not explain why it's not working. But I have tried doing your example by other way and it works well.

Here goes the link.

http://jsbin.com/ajoyug/35/edit

Comment: And if you want to maintain mvvm pattern. Then here goes one more way to do it. http://jsbin.com/ajoyug/46/edit

Comment: Thanks Umakant!! I tried it the normal way n it was working fine..but the MVVM way didnt work out!! Thanks ..you and Ona Both were correct this time :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your approach the grid is *rendered* twice, the first time on Kendo UI `init`ialization (implicit during the first `bind`) and the second when you `bind` the actual data.

The first time the data is still not available and then it fails.

If anyway you want to follow that path you should do:

```
<div id="myListView" data-role="grid" class="transaction-grid"
     data-columns="[
            { field: 'name', title: 'Name', width:'20%' },
            { 
                field: 'age',
                title: 'Age' , 
                width:'35%', 
                footerTemplate: 'Total Count: # if (data.age) { # #= age.count # # } #'  
            }
            ]"
     data-bind="source: dataSource">
</div>
```

i.e. check if `data.age` is available and then is when you print it.

Otherwise, I recommend following @UmankantPatil suggestion and do not use `data-*` but JavaScript for initializing the widgets and binding data.

Check it in the modified version of your JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ajoyug/49/edit)

Comment: Thanks Ona!! Both you and Umakant were correct on this one...your solution worked as well!! :) Thanks for giving a brief explanation of what was happening behind the scenes..