# kendo mvvm grid aggregate error

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, datasource

I can't get the grid aggregates to work in kendo ui with MVVM
I keep getting an error `'count is not defined'`
I have a demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/oMizU/5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with aggregartes but with footer template.

Working demo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/oMizU/9)

I refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172710/kendo-ui-not-able-to-add-footertemplate-to-grid), please see not accepted answer, it is what you need.

Comment: I see it works can you explain what the problem was?

Comment: looks like i forgot http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-group.aggregates

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="example">
    <div data-role="grid" data-row-template="RowTemplate"
        data-columns="[
                        { 'field': 'Name', 'title': 'Name',  'footerTemplate': 'Total'},               
                        { 'field': 'Amount', 'title': 'Amount',  'footerTemplate': '#=kendo.toString(data.Amount ? data.Amount.sum : 0, \'c\')#'}
                      ]"
        data-bind="source: AmountData">
    </div>
</div>
<script id="RowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">   
        <tr>                    
            <td>#= Name # </span></td>          
            <td class="text-right">#if(Amount==0){# #}else{##=kendo.toString(Amount, "c2")##}#</td>          
        </tr>
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({

            AmountData: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "Json",
                data: [{ Name: "abc", Amount: 1000 },
                       { Name: "xyz", Amount: 2500 },
                       { Name: "lmn", Amount: 1700 }],
                aggregate: [{ field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }]
            })
        });

        kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
    });
</script>
```